# Differences between Jakarta Regexp and Java 6 java.util.regex

Tags: java, regex

I am in the process of migrating from Jakarta Regexp to the standard Java 6 regular expressions package `java.util.regex`. I noticed the following difference when not specifying the beginning `^` and end `$` in a regexp: Jakarta Regexp returns true when the regexp matches part of the string, while the Java 6 java.util.regex package does not:

```
String regexp = "\\d";
String value = "abc1abc";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
result = matcher.matches(); // returns false
```

Returns `false` whereas:

```
RE re = new RE(regexp);
re.match(value); // returns true
```

Returns `true`.

What is the reason behind this? I've thought about greedy/lazy matching but that doesn't seem to be relevant in the case of JDK 6 not matching.

Are there any other differences that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [java.util.regex.Matcher.matches()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) method will try to match the complete input string against your regular expression which will be `false`.

If you want to search for the pattern in the input string, you'll need to use [java.util.regex.Matcher.find()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method instead:

```
 result = matcher.find(); // returns true
```

Comment: Are there any important syntactical differences? Or this `matches`/`find` thing is the only one a Jakarta Regexp's user should be concerned about?

Comment: Well, not that I'm aware of, but I'm not at all familiar with the Jakarta regexp's.

Comment: There are. For **example** Jakarta's `[:digit:]` is `\d` in JDK. Or Jakarta's `[:xdigit:]` becomes `\p{XDigit}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find()` instead of `matches()`. It functions exactly as you are expecting.